# iOS How to trigger video to keep playing after exiting fullscreen?

Tags: ios, video, fullscreen

I'm building a website that plays video in iOS.  I have a fullscreen button working in iOS however the video pauses when exiting fullscreen.  Does anyone know a way to either force the video to continue to play upon exiting fullscreen or how to set up a listener that triggers the video to autoplay upon exiting fullscreen?

here is my code:

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('tv'),
    play = document.getElementById('fullscreenbutton'),
    time;
video.addEventListener('webkitbeginfullscreen', function() {
    play.innerText = '';
    window.clearInterval(time);
});
video.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    tv.autoplay();
});
play.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    time = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            video.webkitEnterFullscreen();
        }
        catch(e) {}
    }, 250);
    play.innerText = 'loading ...';
    tv.play();  


});

</script>
```

'''

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `WKScriptMessageHandler` in your iOS app when a button to exit fullscreen mode is tapped then resume your video player.
Here is a workaround on how I would handle this situation.

**Native iOS + JavaScript**

*1 Step: Website front end part*

When exit full screen button is tapped on your website emit an event give it a unique name something like *"exitFullScreenEvent"*

*2 Step: iOS App*

```
import WebKit

ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {


// Helper method to set configurations for your webView in iOS
func configureWebView() {
  ///Add the script message handler into the content controller.
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    /// Give it the same name as on the web front-end part
      contentController.add(self, name: "exitFullScreenEvent")
     let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
     config.userContentController = contentController

/// Most important, when initilizing your web view pass the configuration above
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)

// Layout/add constraints to your webView
// .....

}

// Delegate method to listen an event emitted from your website
   func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

       // TODO: - Resume/ Play your video 
        
    }

}
```

**Pure Website (Javascript only)**

For website only which runs in pure Javascript without any iOS related components and on Safari browser you might want to check this [webkitjs displayingfullscreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlvideoelement/1630493-webkitdisplayingfullscreen)
I Haven't used it before but it worth reading the doc.

But another work around without putting lots of effort is to compare your video player's screen size with the browsers window size ie.. check if browser is full screen if so get the full screen width if it's the same with your video player's size then video is in full screen.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  Just wanted to clarify that this is for a website that runs on desktop and mobile, but it's not an iOS app.  Would this solution still work?

Comment: I edited my answer to include other options for Javascript only, check the last part of my answer.