# Is it possible to set limit of number of images when uploading from ios wkwebview?

Tags: ios, swift, input, wkwebview

I am using wkwebview. I whould like to set limit of number of images to upload. I am wordering if it is possible to set limit from webview input it self or from swift.

I've checked that multiple attribute works. But not the limits.

I hope there is a way to catch input event and set limit.

Comment: <input type="file" id="ex_file" data-type="profile" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png">

webcode is dropped

Answer (score 0):

You can catch javascript input events in Swift a little bit similar to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966578/7551807)